# What is explicitly the isomorphism $M_\omega \otimes_A Ae \cong M\omega(e)$ where $\omega$ is an algebra automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite dim. algebra over a field $k$. Let $\omega:A\rightarrow A$ be an algebra automorphism. Let $M$ be a right $A$-module. Then $M_\omega$ is a right $A$-module such that $M=M_\omega$ as $k$-vector space and the right $A$-module structure is defined by $m⋅a=m\omega(a)$. There is an isomorphism $M_\omega \otimes_A Ae \cong M\omega(e)$, where $e$ is an idempotent of $A$. Is this isomorphism defined explicity by
$$m\otimes ae \mapsto m \cdot ae \mapsto m \omega(a)\omega(e) $$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $M_{\omega} \otimes_A Ae \cong M \omega(e)$ as $k$-vector spaces, then this works fine with the inverse given by $$ M \omega(e) \to M_{\omega} \otimes_A Ae, m \mapsto m \otimes e .$$ 
However, note that $M_{\omega} \otimes_A Ae$ is also an $eAe$-module while $M \omega(e)$ is a $\omega(e)A\omega(e)$-module. If you want to to bring these structures into play it would be better to write $(M \omega(e))_{\omega}$ for the $e A e$-module which is $M \omega(e)$ as $k$-vector space with multiplication $m \cdot a = m \omega(a)$ as you already defined for $M_\omega$.

Comment: In fact, I need an $eAe$-module isomorphism, but as you said, $M\omega(e)$ is not a right $eAe$-module. So, $M_\omega \otimes_A Ae$ is isomorphic to what as right $eAe$-module?  I need this isomorphism explicitly.

Comment: It is isomorphic to $(M \omega(e))_{\omega}$. The isomorphism you wrote down does work then.